# monacaでAngularJSの使い方

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui, angularjs

現在、monacaでAngularJSを使用しております。
angulerJSを複数のページで使用してプログラムを起動したいのですが、うまくいかないことがあります。
例えば、Onsen UI Sliding Menuを使ってpage1.htmlにはアラートで1ページと表示させて、page2.htmlにはアラートで2ページと表示させようとするにはどうすればよろしいですか？

以下に試したコードを載せます
sample1.js

```
 var app = ons.bootstrap("myApp", ["onsen"]);
     app.controller("homeController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
        ons.ready(function() {


  alert('1ページ');

      });
   }]);
```

sample2.js

```
   var app = ons.bootstrap("myApp", ["onsen"]);
    app.controller("homeController1", ["$scope", function($scope) {
        ons.ready(function() {


    alert('2ページ');

        });
    }]);
```

この内容のjsファイルを使ってpage1.htmlに ng-controller="homeController"を指定し、page2.htmlには ng-controller="homeController1"を指定するとエラーが出てしまいます。
AngularJSの使い方がわからず素人の考え方ですみませんがご教授よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sample1.js`、`sample2.js`の順番で読み込んだ場合、`sample1.js`で定義した`app`が、`sample2.js`で定義した`app`に上書きされるため、

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'homeController' is not a function, got undefined

というエラーが出ます。
`sample2.js`の次の行を削除するか、

```
var app = ons.bootstrap("myApp", ["onsen"]);
```

二つのファイルを一つにまとめて記述してください。

```
var app = ons.bootstrap("myApp", ["onsen"]);
app.controller("homeController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    ons.ready(function() {
        alert('1ページ');
    });
}]);
app.controller("homeController1", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    ons.ready(function() {
        alert('2ページ');
    });
}]);
```

Comment: わかりやすいで説明で問題なくプログラムを作成できました。ありがとうございます。